# How to insert values from multiple tables into another table?

Tags: database, triggers, insert, multiple-tables

I'm new to databases. I have 4 tables in total: 3 tables are populated automatically when the user logs on to Facebook. I want the values of the primary keys form those tables to be populated into the 4th table. How do I do this... I need help soon!

This is how the tables look:

```
table:attributes
fb_user : fb_uid, birhtday, gender, email.
company_master : com_id, com_name.
position_master : pos_id, pos_name.
```

And the 4th table goes like this:

```
[table]:[attributes]
work_history : work_id, fb_uid, com_id, pos_id.
```

`fb_uid`, `pos_id` and `com_id` are primary keys.

How to perform this using less database operations? Is there any way to use triggers for this to optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly what type of database are you using?  Secondly, this seems to be a database design issue.  You really should use a single unique primary key across all tables instead of using different primaries and mapping them.  Since your using Facebook it would make sense to use their Facebook id as the primary for all tables then store the other ids as unique fields.  This would also allow you to easily use useful features like joins to retrieve data from multiple tables at once.  If this isn't practical, since for example, your using multiple logins (Facebook Google, etc) for the same user, you would then want to have a lookup table like you suggest as the driving table then use it to help populated the others.  Ideally you want to minimize redundant data as much as possible to reduce the risk of data inconsistencies.  If you are new to databases you should do some reading on database design and database normalization.  A good design will help with scalability and prevent a lot of headaches and frustration.

Comment: i'm using mysql DB.. i'm still a beginner.. thanks anyways. but is there no way to do it with these tables, without making a field common in all the tables??